# why the function method inside of the object doesnt work?

Tags: javascript, function, object

so im doing a object exercise about 2 guys and i have to calculte their BMI.
my code is like this:

```
  const mark = {
  firstName: "Mark",
  lastName: "Miller",
  Mass: "78 kg",
  Height: "1.69 m",

  calcBMI: function () {
    return (
      this.Mass / this.Height ** 2 - this.Mass / (this.Height * this.Height)
    );
  },
};

const john = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Smith",
  Mass: "92 kg",
  Height: "1.95 m",

  calcBMI: function () {
    return (
      this.Mass / this.Height ** 2 - this.Mass / (this.Height * this.Height)
    );
  },
};

if (john.calcBMI > mark.calcBMI) {
  console.log(
    `${john.firstName} has a BMI of ${john.calcBMI} which is higher than ${
      mark.firstName
    } who has a BMI of ${mark.calcBMI()}`
  );
} else {
  console.log(
    `${mark.firstName} has a BMI of ${mark.calcBMI} which is higher than ${
      john.firstName
    } who has a BMI of ${john.calcBMI()}`
  );
}
```

the problem is the "this"?
im having a problem with calcBMI function which its not doing the calculations of BMI

Comment: You did not call the `calcBMI` functions when referencing them

Comment: mark.calcBMI() / john.calcBMI() isnt the call?

Comment: `if (john.calcBMI > mark.calcBMI) {` is not making the call.